# What is JSString and JSInt classes in dart?

Tags: dart, abstract, internals

When i search through the classes like num, String, int.
I have noticed that they are all abstract classes.
What suprised me that the implementation classes for String is JSString and for int JSint.

And this made me think that does the code behind run on javascipt?

what is the meaning of **JS('int', '# | 0', this);**?
This appears often under the hood?

```
int toInt() {
    if (this >= _MIN_INT32 && this <= _MAX_INT32) {
      // 0 and -0.0 handled here.
      return JS('int', '# | 0', this);
    }
    if (JS('bool', r'isFinite(#)', this)) {
      return **JS('int', r'# + 0', truncateToDouble()); // Converts -0.0 to +0.0.**
    }
    // [this] is either NaN, Infinity or -Infinity.
    throw new UnsupportedError(JS('String', '"" + # + ".toInt()"', this));
  }
```

Comment: Those are the implementation types you'll see when you use Dart *for the web* (which incles Dartpad), where Dart is transpiled to JavaScript.  You won't see such types when compiling Dart to VM byte code or to native code.

Comment: Thanks James,
That makes sense, as the code looks javascript:
If i want to see the normal dart code 
how can i see how they have implemented the internals such as num, String, or int ?